# AWS Amplify Configuration: Re-Use Authentication Resource

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've been trying to configure my Application with an existing Backend as suggested in [this link](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#configure-your-application), from the *amplifyConfig.ts* configuration file (see below)

Then, I import the configuration file in the *Login.tsx* page and invoke it by passing  `Amplify.configure(currentConfig)`

1. The first unexpected behavior is that, regardless I define `authenticationFlowType: 'CUSTOM_AUTH'`, when I call the Auth.Signup method, the `authenticationFlowType` is still defined as **"USR_SRP_AUTH"**.

[image]

2. Second, whenever I change the *AmplifyConfig.ts* file, I have to clear all the browsing data in order for those changes to work.

This behavior suggests me I'm doing something wrong, I understand I can deal this via cli, however I would prefer to handle this via code.

Thanks a lot!!

amplifyConfig.ts:

```js
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'CUSTOM_AUTH',

        }
    }
});

// You can get the current config object
const currentConfig = Auth.configure();
```

Login.tsx:

```js
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import currentConfig from '../../services/amplifyConfig';

export function LoginMenu() {

  Amplify.configure(currentConfig);

  // redundant configuration of authenticationFlowType
  Auth.configure({
    authenticationFlowType: 'CUSTOM_AUTH',
  });

  async function onSignup(event: FormEvent) {
    event?.preventDefault();

    try {
      const { user } = await Auth.signUp(UserData);
      console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
  }
}
```